# How to pass mutiple type array in single func

Tags: go

I have multiple structs

```
type Base struct {
    Id string
    Name string
    Code string
}
```

```
type Country struct {
    Base
    ...
}
```

```
type City struct {
    Base
    ...
}
```

And I need to make a function that takes an array of City or Country. Currently, I have one func for each type which is doing the same thing and I guess that isn't the best/good way to do it!

Thanks

Comment: you can create method on the types, these methods cn have the same name. but if country and city are the excat same struct then why make 2 structs?

Comment: you could try to make the function take type of []interface{}

Comment: @Pizzalord Each struct is linked with Gorm and sometimes they are some additional fields ! What do you mean by create method on the types?

Comment: @SivaGuru I tried by isn't working for array -> Cannot use 'offer.Countries' (type []Country) as type []interface{}

Comment: @Clowning you could do func x(array interface{}) instead of x(array []interface{}), since you are sending 1 interface which is an array

Comment: @Pizzalord You right! Thanks! But how can I transform it to an array again ?

Comment: for the function you could use "func modify(a interface{})" and inside the function x , ok := a.([]Country)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to recreate class inheritance in Go. Go does not have class inheritance on purpose. Do not try to recreate it. I believe you're thinking "Country is a Base." That's not correct. Country *embeds* a Base. That's not the same thing. This matters for how you name things. In this case, it seems that "Base" is really "location metadata", so we'll call it that.

```
type LocationMeta struct {
    id   string
    name string
    code string
}
```

And you want an interface to work with for all kinds of locations.

```
type Location interface {
    Id() string
    Name() string
    Code() string
}
```

We can conform LocationMeta to Location, though this is possibly a little strange (is the metadata *really* a Location?). But it works.

```
func (b LocationMeta) Id() string {
    return b.id
}

func (b LocationMeta) Name() string {
    return b.name
}

func (b LocationMeta) Code() string {
    return b.code
}
```

And we can embed LocationMeta in a City:

```
type City struct {
    LocationMeta
}
```

And for free, City now conforms to Location.

That said, usually you don't bother with this kind of embedding for such a small thing with no logic of its own. That's really overkill; I was just demonstrating it because you seem to be using it. Normally, you'd just conform each type itself:

```
type Country struct {
    id   string
    name string
    code string
}

func (c Country) Id() string {
    return c.id
}

func (c Country) Name() string {
    return c.name
}

func (c Country) Code() string {
    return c.code
}
```

The great thing about Go is that it doesn't care how you conform to the interface. City and Country both conform to Location, in completely different ways, and that's totally fine.

So you can then create a city:

```
boston := City{LocationMeta{id: "bos", name: "Boston", code: "bos"}}
```

See how weird this is? We have to create a LocationMeta because of the embedded object. It can be worth it sometimes (and is incredibly powerful), but I would probably have done both City and Country the Country way (with no LocationMeta):

```
us := Country{id: "us", name: "USA", code: "us"}
```

But still, they're both Locations, so we can put them in a slice:

```
locations := []Location{boston, us}
```

And pass them to things:

```
func printLocations(locations []Location) {
    fmt.Println(locations)
}

printLocations(locations)
```

[Playground of this code](https://play.golang.org/p/x9TUKAOjItr)

[Playground using embedding for everything](https://play.golang.org/p/i7G7nG4pyPH)

[Playground of more typical approach with just structs](https://play.golang.org/p/8ZRe4GG5Kd2)

Answer (score 1):

i already posted this in the comments but you can do this

```
func myfunc(in interface{}) {
    switch in.(type) {
    case []Country:
        // country logic here
    case []City:
        // city logic here
    }
}
```